# Host website and server on same domain

Tags: dns

I am trying to run a server on a different host to my website. How can I set it up so that if people connect to certain ports on my domain that they connect to my server, and so my website still works.

Answer (score 0):

Ports exist on the level of TCP and UDP. There is nothing DNS can do to magically change what happens, at the client or your server, on that level.

For your web site, DNS provides translation of its name to a set of IP addresses. The client's browser will then try to talk to port 80 or 443 on one of those addresses. If you want the other server to use the same name as the web site, it must answer requests on other ports on the same set of IP addresses.

If your server is for a protocol that's new and smart enough to use SRV records, you can use that to actually run the server wherever is convenient but still tell the users to connect to the web server name. Check the documentation for details.

If you can't do that, another possibility is to run a small process on the web server machine that listens to the other server's port(s) and forwards all traffic to wherever the server is actually running. The feasibility and details of doing so depends a whole lot of what server it actually is, so I can't really say any more about that.

Or you could just tell the users to use `www.tellusthesoddingname.com` for the web site and `server.tellusthesoddingname.com` for the server and point those names at different IP addresses. Which is by far the simplest and most robust solution.